# I have a SWIG-wrapped vector. How can I tell which type it contains?

Tags: python, c++, swig

In my `.i` file I have a lot of these vector templates:

```
%template(VectorInt) std::vector<int>;
```

I have a need to take one of these vectors, and construct an instance of whatever type the vector contains.

I know I can get the type of the vector, and use my knowledge of the naming conventions to work out a string identical to the desired type, and call the constructor from that.

I cannot count on the vector not being empty.

Is there a more reliable way to get this information?

Comment: Nothing stops you from having a vector of boost::any that has a typemap which means that every element of a vector has a different type. I think you want duck typing in Python for this really.

Comment: @Flexo That makes this the one time I'm glad that I can't use Boost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the vector has elements already, get the type information from any of the elements.

Otherwise, you can call `resize` on the vector, get what you need, then call `clear` afterward.